# Chrome Extension: Set both themes and defaults in single extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-theme

Is it possible to set both chrome themes and chrome defaults (i.e. Default Homepage and Search engine) in single chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

No, since Themes are separate from Extensions (that have the functionality to override settings) - it cannot be one entity. As soon as you declare `"theme"` in the manifest, you can't add normal Extension keys.

An extension cannot cause other extensions (including themes) to be installed. I have briefly thought of using Shared Modules mechanism, but that doesn't allow the imported extension to operate normally - so an imported theme (if that was even possible, which I doubt) wouldn't work.

Additionally, there is no extension API to manipulate themes, and no setting override to configure a theme.